# socket.io 1.4 number of clients connected to server

Tags: socket.io

In socket.io 1.3 I used the following code to obtain the number of clients connected to a server:

```
io.sockets.sockets.length
```

However, as of 1.4 this is no longer working. How do I obtain the number of clients connected to a server in socket.io 1.4?

Answer (score 2):

This prints the number of connected clients:

```
socketIO.engine.clientsCount
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the git history I discovered that the array was changed to an object. The following now works:

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.sockets).length
```

Alternatively, this also works:

```
Object.keys(io.sockets.connected).length
```